# terraform associate subnet to route table issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm having a little trouble associating a single route table to subnets that are created during the Terraform apply. The "aws_subnet" resource already exists and works fine. I am creating an additional resource for "aws_route_table_association" to tell Terraform to use a specific route table for all created subnets rather than the default one. I have tried several combinations but each throws up different errors. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  for_each = var.az_subnets
    
  vpc_id                  = var.vpc_id
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_region.current.name}${each.key}"
  cidr_block              = each.value
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.map_public_ip_on_launch
    
  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    { Name = "${var.name}-${var.classification}-${data.aws_region.current.name}${each.key}" },
    )
}
    
resource "aws_route_table_association" "main" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.main["*"].id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.main[each.value]
  route_table_id = var.route_table_id
}
```

```
**variables.tf**

variable "az_subnets" {
  description = "A map of availability zone names to subnet cidr blocks"
  type        = any
}
    
variable "route_table_id" {
  description = "The id of the route table"
  type        = string
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "aws_subnets" {
  value = {
    main = {
      ids                = values(aws_subnet.main)[*]["id"]
      arns               = values(aws_subnet.main)[*]["arn"]
      availability_zones = values(aws_subnet.main)[*]["availability_zone"]
      cidr_blocks        = values(aws_subnet.main)[*]["cidr_block"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws_subnet` is a resource with key/value pairs since it was created with `for_each`, you need only to specify the resource name:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "main" {
  for_each       = aws_subnet.main
  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = var.route_table_id
}
```

This is a technique of chaining resources with `for_each` and you can find more detailed explanations in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources).

Comment: thank you very much for the swift response. this worked first time! i will definitely read the doc you have sent.